# C# - Synchronous task never being created, causing code to never complete

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, task, msdn

This method should return a task that saves a particular bmp image to disk if it hasn't been saved yet.

I have a ConcurrentDictionary called CachedTileTasks that caches tasks that have already been completed, using the image information as a key. Basically, I don't want to start tasks that save an image that has already been saved.

**The problem I'm running into is that the task is never being created, and the code stops as soon as it starts trying to create the task.** This method is called 9 times, as there are 9 requests coming in-- all of the threads are held up here.

It compiles without error and doesn't throw any exceptions. My code, with some variables renamed, is below:

```
internal Task SaveImage(String imgFilePath, int encodedImageInfo)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("SaveImage called"); // this is being printed
        var imageKey = MakeImageKey(encodedImageInfo);

        Task saveImageToDiskTask = null;
        var foundTask = CachedTileTasks.TryGetValue(imageKey, out saveImageToDiskTask);
        // if the task has been cached, it should be copied into saveImageToDiskTask
        // if not, the task should remain null

        if (foundTask) // you have already done this task
        {
            // if you've already saved the image to disk, we don't want to return a real task
            // so when we execute it, it doesn't take up extra time repeating a task
            return null;

        }
        else // you have not yet done this task, and saveImageToDiskTask should be null
        {
            // creates image we want to save
            var img = new WriteableBitmap(new Uri(imgFilePath)); 

            // this is the last line that it reaches

            saveImageToDiskTask = new Task(() =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Creating the task."); // NOT PRINTING

                new ImageExporter().SaveToDisk(img, scale,
                    TileSize, saveAt, pageNum, user);

                Debug.WriteLine("Tiles have been saved to disk.");
            });

            // cache the task
            CachedTileTasks.GetOrAdd(imageKey, saveImageToDiskTask);

            // return it
            return saveImageToDiskTask;

        }
    }
```

I've looked around StackOverflow and the msdn documentation and nothing has turned up (I apologize if this is a repeat). Any idea what's going on?

Comment: How do you call this method? How do you know that "the task is never being created"?

Comment: Is SaveToDisk asynchronous?

Comment: The task is later created by a function that calls SaveImage but it wasn't being started, only awaited. I added two lines : saveImageTask = SaveImage(imgFilePath, imageInfo); saveImageTask.Start();, so spender's question actually led me to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>`new Task` creates an unstarted task. Did you mean `Task.Run`? Or perhaps you meant `saveImageToDiskTask.Start()`?</strike>

The *answer* is that you have used `new Task` which gives you a cold task that needs to be started.

```
saveImageToDiskTask.Start()
```

will do this for you, or alternatively, you can rustle up a hot task by using `Task.Run`:

```
Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Creating the task."); // NOT PRINTING

            new ImageExporter().SaveToDisk(img, scale,
                TileSize, saveAt, pageNum, user);

            Debug.WriteLine("Tiles have been saved to disk.");
        });
```

which you won't have to start.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @dotctor ?? If you look carefully, you'll see it's an answer, no?

Comment: The task is later created by a function that calls SaveImage but it wasn't being started, only awaited. I added two lines : `saveImageTask = SaveImage(imgFilePath, imageInfo);` `saveImageTask.Start();`, which worked! (thank you for the formatting help, I'm super new!)

Comment: You are trying to clarify the question by asking a question in your answer. So [this is not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag) and this should be a comment.

Comment: No, I'm giving the OP a clear answer, phrased in the form of two options. I'm really not asking for clarification. Sorry this confuses you.

Comment: You can answer when you know the problem. Do you know the problem? No. Are you trying to guess the answer? Yes!

Comment: @dotctor : It's an edit that I really didn't need to make, but hopefully you'll be happier now.

Comment: Now this is okay.+1 @spender

Answer (score 0):

You don't start the task. You need saveImageToDiskTask.Start() for example. You also need to wait for it. Does it have to be a task?